# When are capital letters required on product names?

Tags: terminologie, noms-propres, majuscules

When are capital letters required in product names?

Comment: What products? What do you mean? If I say an IBM computer, in French I will write: un ordinateur IBM. If I say, these wonderful L'Oréal products, I will say: ces produits merveilleux de  L'Oréal.

Comment: @Lambie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_naming

Comment: @jlliagre Please stop it would you?? The question is not clear at all. Your answer discusses brand names for products and the use of brand names that have become the noun for a product. Let's just stop, shall we?? As asked, the answer to the question is: never. But it ***depends*** on what the asker means by: ***product name***.

Comment: A product name is not the same as product naming.

Comment: @Lambie Quoting wikipedia: *Some key steps include specifying the objectives of the branding, **developing the product name itself**, evaluating names through target market testing and focus groups, **choosing a final product name**, and finally identifying it as a trademark for protection.* It seems to be clear to everyone but you what "product name" means.

Comment: @jlliagre Tout cela me fait rire. Il ne faut pas confondre la grammaire de product **naming*** et ***product name***. l'action de donner un nom à un produit et le nom du produit. The OP did not ask about product ***naming*** and there is no "everyone". So far, there is only you and me.

Comment: @Lambie La question porte sur l'existence et/ou la portée d'une contrainte sur les noms de produits, en l'occurrence la présence de capitales. Je ne vois pas comment une telle contrainte pourrait ne pas faire partie de ce que l'on peut appeler le "nommage de produits". C'est le b.a.-ba de la logique...

Answer (score 1):

Product and brand names are expected to follow the standard rules for proper names, i.e. start with a capital letter, but they are never **required** to do so. They are "free" proper nouns and are not required to comply with any orthographic or grammatical rule, especially when used in advertisements and logos. In France, they are registered (*déposés*) at the [INPI](https://www.inpi.fr/fr/comprendre-la-propriete-intellectuelle/la-marque) and the property of their owners.

For example, the obsolete brand name :

[image: > france telecom]

used to break the uppercase requirement for *France* and the accents requirement in *télécom*.

It is now called Orange but its logo still uses a full lowercase spelling:

[image]

The same can occasionally happen for product names like this one :

[image]

or that one:

[image]

There are also opposite cases where the whole product is written in capitals, but doing it doesn't break the French orthography rules. Only the first letter is considered a *majuscule*, the other ones are just *capitales*. e.g.:

[image]

The same name might also be [registered](https://bases-marques.inpi.fr/Typo3_INPI_Marques/marques_fiche_resultats.html?index=14&refId=625890_201641_tmint&y=2095) with the opposite capitalization:

[image]

In plain text, the proper noun requirement for an initial uppercase is normally prevailing so a sentence using that brand name will read *Orange*, une Twingo. On the other hand, if a product name becomes so widely used that it becomes a common name, its leading uppercase letter is often lost. e.g. *un bic*, *un vélux*, *un caddie*, *une freebox*, ...

Of course, product names like ***iPhone*** keep their non standard spelling, nobody writes *Iphone*, but *un ThinkPad* is often written *un thinkpad* and sometimes *un Thinkpad*.

Comment: I disagree with this. Official company names like France Télécom are written like that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_S.A. Anyway, France Télécom is not a product, it's a company. Orange is also not a product.

Comment: @Lambie The rule (or lack of rule) for product names is the same than the one for brand/company names. France Télécom had several spelling changes and the all lowercase Orange logo is quite well known. Answer edited.

Comment: A logo is a logo. Not a product name. Orange, when a service, is called Orange with a capital o.  In any case, the OP was not clear.

Comment: @Lambie an iPhone, a freebox, a bic, a twingo and a vélux are all product names.

Comment: Il ne faut pas tout mettre dans le même sac: logo, nom de société, nom générique d'un produit; nom de marque d'un produit et ainsi de suite.

Comment: @Lambie Et si l’on pouvait y discerner des tendances générales et les regrouper, comme le fait ici jlliagre? *(dont le nom en ce lieu, justement, ne commence pas par une majuscule, sans que l’on soit contraint d’y voir une grave entorse à la langue française)*. Qu’une réponse de cette qualité se soit attirée deux downvotes me semble surréaliste.

Comment: C'est évident que la confusion règne ici malgré touts ces (dois-je préciser petits?) "dé-votants". C'est une perte de temps colossale quand l'honnêteté discursive n'est pas de mise. Alors, bye bye.